# Como configurar DB através de uma variável de ambiente?

Tags: java, tomcat, jsp

Tenho uma aplicação JSP em vários clientes.
Atualmente a configuração do banco de dados fica em um arquivo **variavel.propriet**, e obtenho através do método

```
private static String getUrlBanco() {        
    ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Base.variavel");
    return b.getString("urlbanco");
}
```

O problema é que não é padrão, a localização da base e o arquivo é compactado junto com o war, o que me obriga a gerar um war por cliente.

Queria um meio de que isso fosse setado fora da aplicação, sei lá, por variável de ambiente, por configuração no tomcat...
Aceito sugestões.

Comment: Considere usar uma entrada JNDI no tomcat. Dai você mapeia e consome no web.xml. Assim, vc só precisa reiniciar sua aplicação,

Comment: Ai o usuario e senha do banco ficariam "acessíveis" para o usuários

Comment: Ao administrador do tomcat e SO, provavelmente sim, para os usuário da aplicação não ficaria. Além disso, você pode criptografar a senha quando mapear senha como entrada JNDI no tomcat.

Comment: Como faço isso de mapear a senha criptografada?

Comment: Poderia contextualizar melhor isso? Quem é responsável pelo banco de dados, o cliente ou você? Por que o banco não tem um lugar padrão? Você diz que os dados de acesso ficam dentro do WAR num arquivo texto. Você acha que isso é seguro?

Comment: **Quem é responsável pelo banco de dados?** boa pergunta. Os clientes são responsáveis pelo DB,mas eles não tem o usuário e a senha(política da empresa)(ele que tem que fazer as manutenções, mas não pode ter acesso).

Comment: **Por que o banco não tem um lugar padrão?** pq são prefeituras, e cada uma tem um padrão diferente de onde fica o banco. na maioria o banco fica em um Server diferente do Tomcat

Comment: **Você diz que os dados de acesso ficam dentro do WAR num arquivo texto. Você acha que isso é seguro?** so fica a localização da base, usuario e senha fica dentro de um .java